# php DOM doesn't give all elements

Tags: php, html, dom

I'm trying to use php DOM to grab the src of the images within a "thumbnailCarousel" div in an html. but somehow the loadHTML doesn't contain this element. Does it have something to do with the javascript function in the html? Any suggestions or workarounds is appreciated. Thanks!

sample html:
http://www.crocs.com.sg/crocs-womens-cap-top-flat/12300,en_SG,pd.html?cid=6Z1&cgid=women-footwear-mary-janes-and-flats&intid=home14_carousel_product

div:

```
<div class="thumbnailCarousel" data-jcarousel="true"><ul style="left: 0px; top: 0px;">
<ul style="left: 0px; top: 0px;">
<li>
<img src="http://images.crocs.com/is/image/Crocs/12300_6Z1_ALT100?&amp;fmt=jpeg&amp;qlt=85,1&amp;op_sharpen=0&amp;resMode=sharp2&amp;op_usm=1,1,6,0&amp;iccEmbed=0&amp;printRes=72&amp;wid=60&amp;hei=72" alt="100">
</li>
<li>
<img src="http://images.crocs.com/is/image/Crocs/12300_6Z1_ALT100?&amp;fmt=jpeg&amp;qlt=85,1&amp;op_sharpen=0&amp;resMode=sharp2&amp;op_usm=1,1,6,0&amp;iccEmbed=0&amp;printRes=72&amp;wid=60&amp;hei=72" alt="100">
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that pops out is the markup posted in the question is invalid, missing a `</ul>`.

Comment: hi, yes, didn't copy the whole thing it seems. thanks

Comment: Please print_r() the loadHTML result and post here so we can see what it is missing.

Comment: i'm not sure how to write the code here. i basically used a file_get_contents function and used a dom to loadHTML and the result is: "Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : head in Entity"